# C++ ZIP library for both, 32 and 64 bit

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, software-development, c++

I am looking for a C++ library that supports compressing files. It must work on / be available for both, 32 and 64 bit. We're using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 C++ compiler. It must be available for free and open-source for commercial use (integration into a proprietary license).

I'm looking for a replacement of the [Microsoft Cabinet SDK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310618/microsoft-cabinet-software-development-kit), which does not seem to be supported any more.

I have seen [a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220549/the-best-zip-library-with-public-domain-license), but it's hard to tell, which libraries support both CPU architectures and have an appropriate license.